# Appcelerator UrbanAirship and android (launch app)

Tags: android, coffeescript, push-notification, appcelerator, urbanairship.com

I am using UrbanAirship module in my Appcelerator project to receive push notifications. I am receiving push notifications but when a user clicks on a notification from their notification center on their android device the app doesn't launch. It does on the iPhone though. Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks.

**Update**

Below is the code used to subscribe to push notification on the android

```
UrbanAirship = require("ti.urbanairship")

Ti.API.log "UrbanAirship.pushEnabled " + UrbanAirship.pushEnabled
Ti.API.log "UrbanAirship.pushId " + UrbanAirship.pushId

UrbanAirship.options =
  PRODUCTION_APP_KEY: "XXXX"
  PRODUCTION_APP_SECRET: "XXXX"
  DEVELOPMENT_APP_KEY: "XXXX"
  DEVELOPMENT_APP_SECRET: "XXXX"
  LOGGING_ENABLED: true

UrbanAirship.addEventListener UrbanAirship.EVENT_URBAN_AIRSHIP_CALLBACK, (e) ->
  Ti.API.info "UrbanAirship: Received message " + e.message
  alert e.message

UrbanAirship.addEventListener UrbanAirship.EVENT_URBAN_AIRSHIP_SUCCESS, (e) ->
  token = e.deviceToken
  Ti.App.Properties.setString "device_token", token
  Ti.API.info "UrbanAirship: Received device token " + token

UrbanAirship.addEventListener UrbanAirship.EVENT_URBAN_AIRSHIP_ERROR, (e) ->
  Ti.API.info "UrbanAirship: Error " + e.error

UrbanAirship.pushEnabled = true
```

And on the server side:

```
notification = {"android" => {"alert" => message}, "apids" => android_device_tokens}
Urbanairship.push(notification)
```

Here is the android related code in the tiapp.xml

```
<property name="ti.android.debug" type="bool">true</property>
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <manifest android:installLocation="preferExternal"
        android:versionCode="10" android:versionName="1.0.6"/>
    <manifest>
        <supports-screens android:anyDensity="false"/>
        <application>
            <activity
                android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
                android:name="org.appcelerator.titanium.TiActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        </application>
    </manifest>
</android>
```

Below is the airshipconfig.properties

```
developmentAppKey = xxx
developmentAppSecret = xxx
productionAppKey = xxx
productionAppSecret = xxx

transport = c2dm

c2dmSender = xxxx@gmail.com
inProduction = true

iapEnabled = false
```

And here is the auto generated AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<manifest android:installLocation="preferExternal" android:versionCode="10" android:versionName="1.0.6" package="com.batmanadventure" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <supports-screens android:anyDensity="false"/>
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"/>
  <permission android:name="com.batmanadventure.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
  <application android:debuggable="false" android:icon="@drawable/appicon" android:label="BatmanAdventure" android:name="BatmanadventureApplication">
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="org.appcelerator.titanium.TiActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <receiver android:name="com.urbanairship.CoreReceiver">
      <!-- REQUIRED IntentFilter - For Helium and Hybrid -->
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.urbanairship.push.c2dm.C2DMPushReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
      <!-- Receive the actuggal message -->
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
        <category android:name="com.batmanadventure"/>
      </intent-filter>
      <!-- Receive the registration id -->
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>
        <category android:name="com.batmanadventure"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name="com.urbanairship.push.PushService"/>
    <receiver android:name="ti.modules.titanium.urbanairship.IntentReceiver"/>
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:label="BatmanAdventure" android:name=".BatmanadventureActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.Titanium">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="org.appcelerator.titanium.TiTranslucentActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"/>
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="org.appcelerator.titanium.TiModalActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"/>
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="ti.modules.titanium.ui.TiTabActivity"/>
    <activity android:name="ti.modules.titanium.ui.android.TiPreferencesActivity"/>
    <service android:exported="false" android:name="org.appcelerator.titanium.analytics.TiAnalyticsService"/>
  </application>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="com.batmanadventure.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
</manifest>
```

Comment: You should post your notification code

Comment: Did you follow the instructions under the "Enabling Push Notifications" [here](https://docs.urbanairship.com/display/DOCS/Getting+Started%3A+Android%3A+Helium+Push)?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, it surely is not a problem with urbanairship library. Because urbanairship won't miss on something this basic.
Check [Custom Handling of Push Events](https://docs.urbanairship.com/display/DOCS/Client%3A+Android%3A+Push#ClientAndroidPush-CustomHandlingofPushEvents)

Here, the launch of activity is being handled a little differently by checking for `PushManager.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_OPENED` and then calling `UAirship.shared().getApplicationContext().startActivity(launch);`

In your `ti.modules.titanium.urbanairship.IntentReceiver`

```
public class IntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String logTag = "PushSample";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      String action = intent.getAction();
      if (action.equals(PushManager.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_OPENED)) {
          Log.i(logTag, "User clicked notification. Message: " + intent.getStringExtra(PushManager.EXTRA_ALERT));

          logPushExtras(intent);

          Intent launch = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
          launch.setClass(UAirship.shared().getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
          launch.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
          UAirship.shared().getApplicationContext().startActivity(launch);
    }
}
```

You can set the activity to be launched in `launch.setClass(UAirship.shared().getApplicationContext(),`**MainActivity.class**`);`

Answer (score 1):

It could be a problem with urbanairship library. If they did not add a PendingIntent to the notification, it will not open your app.

I just looked at urbanairship.com but it does not seem they provide source code for Android, only the jar.

Comment: Thank you. That might be it. I have seen PendingIntent mentioned in Android related forums. Is there a way I could do that myself. Or is this something I can add in the AndroidManfiest file. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I don't think it is something you can solve without urbanairship source code. You could try sending them an email and explaining what's happening in your app, or clearly asking if they did attach a PendingIntent to their notifications.